# svyby and empty cells

Tags: r, survey

Hopefully this is a simple problem with a simple solution. I have weighted survey data that was collected in several countries.  I am trying to create a table that displays proportional responses to a particular survey question by country with corresponding CI and SE. Using svyby in the "survey" package seems to work just fine for the first question, where there is at least one response at each factor level within each country.

```
svyby(~V34c,~V4, design = data, svymean, na.rm=T,vartype=c("ci","se"))
```

yields the expected output in general form:

[Country, Neither agree nor disagree, V34cNo data, V34cOverall Agree, ...]

AU-Australia, 0.31459269, 0.0425825851, 0.2935771 ...

BE-Belgium, 0.31884528, 0.0895231917, 0.2024003 ...

BG-Bulgaria, 0.29237157, 0.0649909093, 0.4632688 ...
...

However, when running the same code on a question where some factor levels are empty (say, there are no observations for "overall agree" in Bulgaria), I get funky output:

```
svyby(~V34c,~V4, design = data, svymean, na.rm=T,vartype=c("ci","se"))
```

[Country, 1, 2, 3, ...]
AU-Australia, c(0.165198816, 0.026821016, 0.734128167, 0.073852001, 0.012071501, 0.006550439, 0.014495680, 0.008485131, 0.141539109, 0.013982390, 0.705717158, 0.057221449, 0.188858522, 0.039659641, 0.762539177, 0.090482553), c(0.155043789, 0.043788518, 0.744404801, 0.056762893, 0.006518719, 0.003685319, 0.007855954, 0.004167357, 0.142267333, 0.036565425, 0.729007414, 0.048595024, 0.167820244, 0.051011610, 0.759802187, 0.064930763), c(0.305804298, 0.016750805, 0.461542910, 0.215901986, 0.015591287, 0.004766330, 0.016740671, 0.014762079, 0.275245937, 0.007408969, 0.428731799, 0.186968842, 0.336362659, 0.026092642, 0.494354022, 0.244835130), ...

BE-Belgium, c(0.165198816, 0.026821016, 0.734128167, 0.073852001, 0.012071501, 0.006550439, 0.014495680, 0.008485131, 0.141539109, 0.013982390, 0.705717158, 0.057221449, 0.188858522, 0.039659641, 0.762539177, 0.090482553), c(0.155043789, 0.043788518, 0.744404801, 0.056762893, 0.006518719, 0.003685319, 0.007855954, 0.004167357, 0.142267333, 0.036565425, 0.729007414, 0.048595024, 0.167820244, 0.051011610, 0.759802187, 0.064930763), c(0.305804298, 0.016750805, 0.461542910, 0.215901986, 0.015591287, 0.004766330, 0.016740671, 0.014762079, 0.275245937, 0.007408969, 0.428731799, 0.186968842, 0.336362659, 0.026092642, 0.494354022, 0.244835130), ...

BG-Bulgaria, c(0.165198816, 0.026821016, 0.734128167, 0.073852001, 0.012071501, 0.006550439, 0.014495680, 0.008485131, 0.141539109, 0.013982390, 0.705717158, 0.057221449, 0.188858522, 0.039659641, 0.762539177, 0.090482553), c(0.155043789, 0.043788518, 0.744404801, 0.056762893, 0.006518719, 0.003685319, 0.007855954, 0.004167357, 0.142267333, 0.036565425, 0.729007414, 0.048595024, 0.167820244, 0.051011610, 0.759802187, 0.064930763), c(0.305804298, 0.016750805, 0.461542910, 0.215901986, 0.015591287, 0.004766330, 0.016740671, 0.014762079, 0.275245937, 0.007408969, 0.428731799, 0.186968842, 0.336362659, 0.026092642, 0.494354022, 0.244835130), ...

...

The code seems to work they way I expect it to when I remove the offending country from the dataset, but I'm hoping there's another solution.

Thanks!

Comment: i believe you need to reset the factor levels.  `data <- update( data , V34c = factor( V34c ) )`  if that does not solve the problem, then please provide a reproducible example thanx  :P

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!

Comment: @AnthonyDamico - that worked for me too, you should submit that as the answer